# postfix local delivery mbox Permission denied

Tags: postfix, permissions, aliases, mbox

I recently switched from sendmail to postfix.
My `/etc/aliases` says:

```
[...]
postmaster: /var/spool/mail/postmaster
[...]
```

The permissions are:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 postfix mail 4.9M Aug  9 13:54 /var/spool/mail/postmaster
```

before it was g=r, I changed it to g=rw for testing.

The error I get is:

```
[...] postfix/local[4554]: 2D4EF8C1626: to=<postmaster@DOMAIN>, [...] status=bounced (cannot append message to file /var/spool/mail/postmaster: cannot open file: Permission denied)
```

I don't have a unix user postmaster, if that's relevant.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this, without creating a new user, is to set in `main.cf` the parameter `default_privs = mail`.

Keep in mind that it is discouraged to use `root` or `postfix` for [`default_privs`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#default_privs).